# Should I put a user id in a REST url or get it from authentication

Tags: node.js, api, rest, authentication, express

I'm building a RESTful api with Express.js. Let's say I have some `Users` which own `Resources`. A good way to get the `Resources` of a specific `User` would be: `GET /users/:user_id/resources`.

I implemented authentication for the api and can thus get the `user_id` from `req.user.user_id` instead of from the url. This means I could just use `GET /resources` to get the resources from the authenticated user.

My question: is this good practice and why (or why not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it is bad practice. Resources should return all resources, not filtered in any way. I would say it is better to have an additional endpoint `/user/resources`. In this way responses will be:

1. `/users/15/resources` - will give resources for user 15 if allowed or 403.
2. `/user/resources` - will give resources for the authenticated user (if I am user 15, then this gives the same response as in 1.) OR 404 OR 403.
3. `/resources` - will give not filtered resources (if it is prohibited, then just don't create this endpoint, or return only public resources).

Comment: I didn't think of using `/user/resources` as an endpoint. The singularity of user indeed indicates that the retrieved resources belong to a single user. I guess it is then clear that the `user_id` is in that case retrieved from the authentication. Thank you!